# How to pass data without segue and storyboard programming?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to pass data from vc1 to vc2.

vc1 have many buttons.
vc2 have many elements and detect the user press which button that show different element.
So,I just write two .swift files to change the different UI.

vc1:

```
let vc2 = vc2()

func buttonClick(sender:UIButton)
{
    switch sender {

    case button1:
        vc2.data = "name"
        present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break

    case button2:
        vc2.data = "photo"
        present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break

    default:
        print("default")
    }
```

vc2:

```
    var data:NSString = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("data is here : \(data)")

    switch data {

    case "name":
    print("here is button1View")
        break
    case "photo":
    print("here is button2View")
        break
    default:
    print("default View")
    }

}
```

print data is null.
what should I do about this idea?

Comment: What is your problem again ? What is not working ?

Comment: var data:NSString = "", 
this is wrong, 
write it as  var data:NSString?  In current scenario you are initializing the data variable

Comment: I know. how to pass the data?

Comment: Move your code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Why don't you simply add an initial method for VC2 and pass data as parameter. E.g `init(data: NSData?)`

Comment: Are you sure this is your code without any changes? May be you have something like this **var data:NSString? = ""**?

Answer (score 0):

the problem look like that u didn't init vc2 so i write u an example and its works for me

```
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"vc2") as! vc2
    switch sender {

    case button1:
        vc2.data = "name"
        present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break

    case button2:
        vc2.data = "photo"
        present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break

    default:
        print("default")

}
}
```

and vc2

```
    var data:NSString = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("data is here : \(data)")

    switch data {

    case "name":
        print("here is button1View")
        break
    case "photo":
        print("here is button2View")
        break
    default:
        print("default View")
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this in vc1

```
 let vc2 = UIStoryboard(name: "storeyBoardID", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "stroyboardIdOfcontroller") as? viewController2
```

and

```
vc2.data = "name"
```

and vc2 declare the data variable like this

```
var data:NSString?
```

Hope this will help you